# Python and terminal: keep python environment after the file has been executed

Tags: python, linux, windows

I have to run a Python file from the Windows terminal (Windows PowerShell). I want that after the file has been executed (`python foo.py`), python keeps open with the variables defined in the file.

If it is unclear what I want, I want the same behavior as IDLE, after the file has been executed, you can write code in the IDLE command line and the variables defined in the file are stored in current session.

I need this for Windows now, but I might also need this for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the `-i` parameter as follows:

```
python -i foo.py
```

(Transcribed from `python` help):

```
python -h
```

> ```
> usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
> Options (and corresponding environment variables):
> …
> -i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
>          if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
> …
> ```